# Unable to STOP UwAmp MySQL service

Tags: mysql, uwamp

uwamp user has server privileges "shutdown" but when I click STOP button from UwAmp 3.1.0 control panel the MySQL does not stops.

I have try with root password also does not shutting down.

I try to run UwAmp with "Run as administrator" from windows but still nothing and I kill proccess from Task Manager.

Any solutions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. And if anyone search for this.
In my hosts file I was have my static ip as localhost, and I change it to 127.0.0.1

for example

Previous hosts file

```
192.168.1.50 localhost
```

change it to default

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```